# Create in Eclipse project using existing C files

Tags: c, eclipse, import

I have several .c files and I want to build, compile and edit this C code in Eclipse.

What is the best way to have these files added to my Eclipse IDE in order to compile the code?

Comment: Read the Eclipse documentation, use a search engine...

Comment: Actually I did, and I found information about adding code to an existing project (by for example creating an empty project). But when I build the project, It says that there are no binaries found.

Comment: Is the compiling suite installed?

Comment: Yes, everything is properly installed. In the Eclipse documentation, they create a new C Project with a Helloworld Makefile. But in the wizard, when creating such a new project, I don't have the option to create a Makefile Helloworld project. Therefore I cannot built and run the project because no binaries are created after creating the empty project including my .c files.

Comment: Well, you are going to need a friend to debug your Eclipse installation... or you can just write a simple Makefile yourself and run make from the console.

Comment: I wouldn't do your own Makefile in this situation, but maybe post some more detail--e.g., your Eclipse version/flavor.  If it's not a recent installation, maybe try a new installation.  (You can have multiple Eclipse installations on one PC and they shouldn't conflict.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general:

go to the 'Project Explorer' window

right click the project to be modified

click 'import'

in the 'import' window, open 'General' then click 'File System' then click 'next'

in the 'import'/File system window

use the 'From directory: 'Browse' button to select where the files to add are located

'drill in' to the the desired file(s) are displayed then click 'ok'

then click the check box to the left of each file to be added to the project

the next window will list all the files in the selected directory

click the check box to the left of each file to be added to the project

then click 'Finish'

The 'Project Explorer window will be re-displayed,

open your project (in the 'Project Explorer' window so each of the file names is displayed.

The files you added will be there

HOWEVER, they will be considered linked resources.

To make them part of the source and header files for the project, copy them to the (your project name) directory in the eclipse work space